# Find a column/row of item of a QTableWidget by name

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I try to find the column of a header cell of `QtableWidget` as follow

```
column = QtCore.QObject.findChild(mytableWidget, unicode("NAME")).column() # it should retruns 0
```

where `mytableWidget` is the table which is already defined

```
    self.mytableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.frame)
    ...
    ...
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("NAME")
    self.mytableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item) # searching this item
```

but I get the following error

```
TypeError: 'PySide.QtCore.QObject.findChild' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtCore.QObject.findChild(unicode)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtCore.QObject.findChild(PyTypeObject, unicode = QString())
```